# How to authenticate to Hadoop from command line? Removing `ls: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled` error

Tags: security, hadoop, authentication, kerberos

I am setting up Kerberos authentication on a Hadoop cluster.  From a machine outside the cluster, whenever I do `hadoop fs -ls`, I get the following message: `ls: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]`, which is nice, since that is what I want.  But now my question is, how do I actually execute that command succesfully? I know that I cannot proceed if I don't authenticate, but how do I authenticate from the command line?

Comment: Isn't kinit and then hadoop comand working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below steps

`Server`

```
kadmin.local
addprinc user@realm.com
```

`Client`

```
kinit user@realm.com
```

`klist` to view the principals

Answer (score 0):

Things need to be modified both in the Hadoop server and in the client that is trying to access it.

**Server**

In the server you need to add a new user to the realm, and for that you use the following commands:

In the `kadmin.local` shell, type the following command: `addprinc user@realm.com`.  When prompted, type the password twice.

**Client**

Be sure that you have kinit installed and pointing to the Kerberos server of the cluster, and run the following command to acquire a token from the Kerberos server: `kinit user@realm.com`.  To verify that you succeeded acquiring it, type `klist`.

And last, but not least: be sure that your client `core-site.xml` file is in agreement with the corresponding server-side configuration.  Particularly, be sure that the value for the key `hadoop.security.authentication` is not `simple` in your client if it is not `simple` in your server.